# Apply border to TD that stays inside the TD dimensions

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

In a calendar application I'm using the following (slightly simplified) style to highlight the currently selected table cells in a html table:

```
border:solid 2px black;
```

The problem is, that this is expanding to outside the table cell thus expanding the containing row, like seen in the following images:

**unselected**

[image]

**selected**

[image]

Is there a CSS method to force the border to "stay inside" the table cell and not expand the containing row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

so that your border wont span other cells

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction, although this didn't work for the `td`, but only when I added a wrapping `div` inside the `td` and applied the `box-sizing` to that div.

Answer (score 1):

Along with `box-sizing`:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to force the browser to incorporate the width of the `border` (and `padding`) inside of the declared width, there's also the potential use of `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000;
```

Although, unfortunately, while this will give a pseudo-border, it can only be a solid border.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  box-sizing:border-box
}
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
```

I use this at the top of my stylesheets. The first one sets the `box-sizing` property on the entire document to `border-box`, which takes any padding and borders into account when setting an elements height and width. Without this the default box model applies where an element first gets height and width, then padding, then borders.

The second line helps if you're using components or code from someone else where they might have set `box-sizing` to something else. It means that for those snippets of code, they'll keep their `box-sizing`. The inheritance means that once the containing element's closed, the next element will inherit back up the DOM, ultimately taking `border-box`.

Chris Coyier did a nice piece on [inheriting box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/) in 2014 which goes into some more detail.